# How to create a resizable window with rounded-corners in win32

Tags: c++, winapi, window, rounded-corners, resizable

I'm trying to create a Win32 window that has rounded corners and is resizable both horizontally and vertically. My first approach was to create BITMAP of a rounded rectangle and draw it to the screen in conjunction with setting the windows style to WS_EX_LAYERED and setting the transparency key to the outside color of the rounded rectangle.

This works, but it only looks good if the window is a fixed size. If I allow the user the resize the window and stretch the bitmap along with it, the rounded corners look stretched out, too. Is there a way to create a window that has nice, smooth rounded corners and is resizable in windows? Eventually, I would also like to add a drop shadow to the window as well.

Comment: Just don't stretch the corner bitmaps, only use them on the corners.  Stretching the hor/ver bitmaps isn't a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try to mix the Windows API functions [CreateRoundRectRgn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183516(VS.85).aspx) and [SetWindowRgn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa930600.aspx). A very simple example can be found at [pInvoke.net web site.](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowrgn)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a window without any frame, use WS_EX_LAYERED to get transparency, then either draw the window including your custom frame "normally" in WM_PAINT, or you compose an off-screen bitmap, and use `UpdateLayeredWindow`  (the latter method is more efficient).

You have to adjust what you draw to the current size of the window, of course. Typically, you would compose it from different elements -  e.g. use four "corner" bitmaps (or an ellipse function) to draw the corners, then draw the border, etc.

Also, you can handle `WM_NCHITTEST` to assign "title" / "border" / "corner" functionality (i.e. moving and sizing the window) to arbitrary areas of your window.

Comment: ha? WM_PAINT is not fired with WS_EX_LAYERED. And WM_NCHITTEST is not fired without WS_SIZEBOX/WS_THICKFRAME.

Comment: WM_PAINT does get called when you use WS_EX_LAYERED in conjunction with SetLayerdWindowAttributes. Regarding WM_NCHITTEST I'm pretty certain it does fire - I've used it before to make a non-resizable non-framed window draggable

Comment: Oh, so WM_PAINT gets disabled on the first call to UpdateLayeredWindow then? Good to know. You're right about WM_NCHITTEST, I was remembering it wrong, sorry for the noise.

Comment: Yes, I remember now: you do get WM_NCHITTEST but if you return any of the resize constants like HTBOTTOMLEFT, etc. they get ignored, only HTCAPTION and HTCLIENT really works if you don't specify WS_THICKFRAME. I just tested this now.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of drawing the corner with a pre-existing bitmap, you'll want/need to draw an ellipse (or whatever) in the correct shape, then composite that to the screen. For example, you might decide on an ellipse with each radius being 5% of the window size in that direction.